# C# RX (System.Reactive) - Async - Publish an IEnumerable<DataRow> to multiple observing data handers

Tags: c#, asynchronous, system.reactive

I'm new to RX.

I'd like to traverse an IEnumerable and publish to multi DataHandlers that process the data in their respective threads.

Below is my sample program. The publish works and a new thread is created, but the 3 RowHandlers are all running in 1 thread. I need 3 threads. What is the best way to implement this?

```
class Program
{

    public class MyDataGenerator
    {
        public IEnumerable<int> myData()
        {
            //Heavy lifting....Don't want to process more than once.
            yield return 1;
            yield return 2;
            yield return 3;
            yield return 4;
            yield return 5;
            yield return 6;
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyDataGenerator h = new MyDataGenerator();
        Console.WriteLine("Thread id " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString());
        //
        var shared = h.myData().ToObservable().Publish();
        ///////////////////////////////
        //  Row Handling Requirements
        //
        //      1. Single Scan of IEnumerable. 
        //      2. Row handlers process data in their own threads. 
        //      3. OK if scanning thread blocks while data is processed
        //

        //Create the RowHandlers
        MyRowHandler rn1 = new MyRowHandler();
        rn1.ido = shared.Subscribe(i => rn1.processID(i));
        MyRowHandler rn2 = new MyRowHandler();
        rn2.ido = shared.Subscribe(i => rn2.processID(i));
        MyRowHandler rn3 = new MyRowHandler();
        rn3.ido = shared.Subscribe(i => rn3.processID(i));
        //
        shared.Connect();
    }

    public class MyRowHandler
    {
        public IDisposable ido = null;
        public void processID(int i)
        {
            var o = Observable.Start(() =>
                                        {
                                            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Start Thread ID {0} Int{1}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, i));
                                            Thread.Sleep(30);
                                            Console.WriteLine("Done Thread ID"+Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString());
                                        }
                                    );
            o.First(); 
        }
    }
}
```

---

Discovery :

The coding speed & code quality gains one receives from Rx come at the expense of performance.  Task/Delegates are without a doubt multiples faster.  That means that the most important thing one needs to learn about Rx is when to use Rx.  Below is a draft summary guideline.  For large volumes I can see use for Rx in chuncking, combining, and other many stream-many handler models; however, basic Async should not use rx.

I'd post an image with a matrix guideline, but the site won't let me post images

Comment: Which version of Rx are you using?

Comment: It is not clear from your explanation, what is the problem you are solving. If "wait for heavy lifting task", than async call would do it. If avoid recomputation, like you stated, than var cachedData = myData().ToArray() would do it without Rx.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your sequencing requirements correctly and you want three parallel running scans, you can just observe on the TaskPool and subscribe from there;

```
...

//Create the RowHandlers
MyRowHandler rn1 = new MyRowHandler();
rn1.ido = shared.ObserveOn(Scheduler.TaskPool).Subscribe(i => rn1.processID(i));

...
```

Note that since you're then running asynchronously and your main thread doesn't wait for the scans to get done, your program will terminate right away unless you for example put a `Console.ReadKey()` at the end of the program.

EDIT: Regarding running the same thread "all the way", you're scheduling a bit strangely for that. If you drop the observable in the rowhandler, you can use Scheduler.NewThread and get good results;

```
...

var rowHandler1 = new MyRowHandler();
rowHandler1.ido = shared.ObserveOn(Scheduler.NewThread).Subscribe(rowHandler1.ProcessID);

...

public void ProcessID(int i)
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Start Thread ID {0} Int{1}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, i));
    Thread.Sleep(30);
    Console.WriteLine("Done Thread ID" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
}
```

That will give each subscription its own thread, and stay with it.

Comment: Awesome. Worked like a charm.  I haven't gotten to ObserveOn in the API documentation and samples.  I'm on .NET 3.5 so I had to use Scheduler.ThreadPool.   TaskPool does seem to be in the namespace.

Comment: Sadly, Rx seems to be significantly slower than manually managing the threading.   It's almost as if every row forces a new ThreadPool request...releasing and allocating a new thread every time.  Is this true?  Or is there a way to make it keep the same thread until all the rows are processed?

Comment: @user1332889 Updated answer with info how to achieve that.

Comment: Take a look at the `EventLoopScheduler` if you want to prevent the overhead of creating new threads.